# Java in Mac terminal:could not find or load main class

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I'm trying to run my java program in Mac terminal. This picture shows my contents in Netbeans, I wanna run "SeqList":

[image: This picture shows my contents in Netbeans,I wanna run "SeqList"]

First I code

```
javac SeqList.java
```

then it successfully create SeqList.class,whose classpath is /Users/andychao/Desktop/JAVVVVA/DataStractureTest/src/homework/SeqList.class

(my project name is "DataStractureTest",my package name is "homework")

But when I tried

`java SeqList`

or

```
java homework.SeqList
```

or even

`java /Users/andychao/Desktop/JAVVVVA/DataStractureTest/src/homework/SeqList`

I always received

```
Error: Could not find or load main class SeqList
```

I read other people's answers to this problem,but still cannot figure out it.

Is there anybody who can give me some specific advice? THX!

Comment: 1) Why can't you run this from NetBeans? 2) It's hard to help without knowing if there is even a main method in that class 3) Even if this worked, you likely need to add the other classes to the classpath when you compile

Comment: @cricket_007 (1)I can run it in NetBeans (2)it has a main method (3)I just wanna run this ".class" document,and there is only one java class in it

Comment: Seqlist doesn't extend or implement that other list class?

Comment: No,it just imports some packages.